# WiFi antenna's shield

Tags: antenna, wifi

Newbie question:
I've an Android TV stick (Rikomagic MK802 III) and I'm having wifi signal problems. I've opened the device, and this is what I've found:
[image: shield connected]

Both the wire and the shield are connected to the antenna, **is this normal?**
The connection to the board is identical, wire and shield.

Here is another photo so you can see the entire antenna: 
[image]

Comment: I can't really tell from the picture, but are they both connected to the same metal strip on the antenna? If you have a multimeter you can do a connectivity test between the shield and the wire.

Comment: yes, they are both soldered.

Comment: I'll leave the thorough explanation to RF guys (if we have any), but this looks quite normal to me. The antenna's shape itself would form a needed impedance at the emission frequency, even if there's a short at DC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.  Note that the shield and the center conductor are not connected at the same place.  The current path between the two points is a significant fraction of the wavelength, so this is perfectly plausible for a antenna.

When trying to understand antennas, you can't think in DC or viewing them as lumped systems.  Two points 1/4 wavelength apart, even if shorted DC-wise, are very different connection points.